# Eclipse fallo al ejecutarse

Tags: eclipse

tengo un problema y es el siguiente: he instalado java en el disco c y los programas me los guarda en eh (seleccionado por mi), he hecho varios proyectos y al rato he cerrado eclipse. Ahora  estoy intentado ejecutar eclipse pero no me deja. Alguna solucion